# Is there an idiom for not "applying a double standard"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom for not "applying a double standard"?

> I hope that if we find out his dad is the guilty one instead of her
> dad, he **doesn't apply a double standard** and does what he told her to
> do to herself.

This is too wordy, I am wondering if there's a good expression for this. I think "take up own advice" could be used, but sometimes there's no advice, and the person doesn't give an advice and says something harsh or worse.

Comment: Your example is so complicated, it's hard to figure out what 's going on. You have two dads, one son, an unidentified "her", and some guilt floating around. What did they all do?

Comment: Everything up to your comma makes sense after the comma we have a *He*, being *his dad*, not applying a double standard to *Her*. Who is *Her*?  Is *Her* the her of *her dad*?  Because in your sentence it is not at all clear who the *Her* of the double standard application is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is quite hard to follow without more context, but whatever it means, I think one of these expressions applies:

- *I hope he **lives up to his own standards** and does ...*
- *I hope he **applies his own standards to himself** and does...*

They're both used idiomatically in a situation where person A declares an appropriate punishment for person B because they committed a particular offence, and then it turns out that person A actually did this offence, and we hope that person A accepts their own declared punishment.

We use this often with politicians who scream that some other politician should resign for lying/doing drugs/seeing a prostitute/whatever, then that politician is caught doing the same thing and inevitably has a different opinion on what his own punishment should be.

Comment: Those are two interesting idioms, especially the first one.

Answer (score 2):

What's sauce for the goose is sauce for the gander.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).